# Is 结尾 a (separable) verb?

Tags: meaning, word, verbs

[Tatoeba](https://tatoeba.org/en/sentences/show/1878074) has the sentence

> 这个故事仓促地**结**了**尾**。

wherein 结尾 is being used as a separable verb.  Honestly, before seeing this sentence, I didn't even realize 结尾 could be used as a verb.

CC-CEDICT includes a verb definition for 结尾:

> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E7%BB%93%E5%B0%BE) 结尾: (jié​wěi)​ ending / coda / to wind up

But ChatGPT thinks it's unusual:

> ... In the sentence "这个故事仓促地结了尾," the usage of "结了尾" is a bit unusual. The more common expression would be "故事仓促地结束了" (The story ended hastily). ...

And it has been hard finding examples of 结尾 being used as a verb online, such as at [YouDao](https://youdao.com/result?word=%E7%BB%93%20%E5%B0%BE&lang=en) and [Baidu](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E7%BB%93%E4%BA%86%E5%B0%BE).

My Pleco dictionary ("GF") has a verb definition 结束；完成最后的工作; one example sentence is 这件事由我来结尾。

**Question**: Is 结尾 a (separable) verb?

Maybe it's worth knowing this rare usage exists, but I shouldn't use it or I'll get marked down.

Answer (score 1):

If you search the corpus, "结了尾" exists but is very rare:

> 报道还再次对于为躲避右翼攻击，古义人一直是如何“处世”的做了点评，最后以“应该学习内弟不怕再次被刺的勇气”**结了尾** 。

结尾了 is much more common:

> 时间已经很紧了，再举出几件事实，再引述一句他的话，就只好这样**结尾了**。

> 但这几天实在是精疲力尽，便草草**结尾了**。

> 只要你们把这个吊桥砍断，就有可能以喜剧**结尾了**。

I think "结了尾" is corrupted from "收了尾". As verbs, both "结尾" and "收尾" can mean to finish something. However, 收尾 is officially a separable verb and "收了尾" is more common than "结了尾":

> 她脸绯红了，飞快地将故事**收了尾**。

> 双方都不再贸然出击，上半场就这样略显沉闷地**收了尾**。

Also a few phrases derived from 收尾:

> 必须承认，王传志是个很能干的人，为国家做出了重大贡献。部党组希望他能**收个豹尾** 。(豹尾 is used to describe a strong, remarkable ending.)

> 我狂热地写作：十幕剧，**收不住尾**的长篇小说，一卷又一卷短篇小说，大量的诗歌。(收不住尾 = unable to write an ending to a novel.)

Answer (score 1):

> Is 结尾 a (separable) verb?

Yes. Per 汉典:

- **[結 <动>](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E7%BB%93)** - 植物生长果实, 结果(bear fruit)。
- [结尾](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E7%BB%93%E5%B0%BE) - 结束(ending/terminate).

Similar words - 结(了)案; 结(了)婚; 结(了)帳